# Templated unions in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unions

Does the c++11 standard say anything about templated unions?  (I can't find anything in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf, but I haven't read it that carefully.)

I have

```
template<typename T>
union u {
  T a;
  char b;
};

template<typename T>
u<T> make_u(T t) {
  return { .a = t };
}

int main() {
  return make_u<int>(1).a;
}
```

This code causes `icpc -std=c++11` to say `error: a designator into a template-dependent type is not allowed`, `g++ -std=c++0x` to say `error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token`, and `g++ -std=c++11` (version 4.8.0 (experimental)) to say `internal compiler error: in lookup_field_1, at cp/search.c:387`.  I can get around this by replacing `{ .a = t }` with `t`.  However, I could not do this for fields which are not the first member of the union.  Is there a way to pick some member other than the first one in a templated union, where the relevant member is template-dependent?  (I could, of course, declare a union on the stack, and set the member equal to the value I want.  But I could not do this in an initializer list or in a `constexpr` function.)

Comment: General question on templated union: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20743582/1147772

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `{ .a = t }` syntax is a non-standard GNU extension, so its interaction with other C++ features is outside the scope of the C++ standard.

Solution: write standard C++:

```
u<T> make_u(T t) {
  u<T> r;
  r.a = t;
  return r;
}
```

EDIT: AFAIK, in C++11, you can give your union a constructor (a constexpr if you like) that does the initialization you need. Example: http://ideone.com/s4GHjU