# Can union be templated?

Tags: c++, templates, unions

It seems unions can be templated in c++11, they are used for example in [the reference implementation of std::optional](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp).

Was that possible before c++11 ?

Comment: `std::optional` is no more :-(

Comment: (It's an odd decision to place the init flag at the top of the class and not the data member. I would have thought that cheap dereferencing would be desirable moreso than validity checking.)

Comment: @KerrekSB That's sad for std::optional :(. For the implementation thing, it seems even [boost::optional implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) puts its boolean before its data.

Comment: @KerrekSB why is `std::optional` not there anymore? whats the reason

Comment: @Koushik: no idea. I guess the committee felt there was a lack of experience with it.

Comment: To be clear, `std::optional` _is_ a thing as of C++17.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it seems that this has always been allowed. A union is a class, and a template is either a function or a class template.

Relevant parts of the standards:

- [temp]

  > The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
  >
  > — declare or define a function or a class, [...]
- [class]

  > A *union* is a class defined with the class-key `union`

(So one might argue that the new type trait [`std::is_class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) is a slight misnomer; the traits are supposed to partition the space of types, and so `is_union` is a separate, mutually exclusive trait.)

Comment: I did not even know that "A union is a class" ! Glad i asked this question :)

Answer (score 27):

Yes, a particularly useful application is to represent a type simultaneously as a byte array:

```
template <typename T>
union test
{
    unsigned char ch[sizeof(T)];
    T variable;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In place of a union you can also use std::variant as of c++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant